# How to create Nuget package with nested dependencies

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I'm working on a .NET Core solution. For one of the projects within the solution, I need to build a Nuget package.

Project A has a reference to another project B in the solution, set up as a project reference. Project B has a dependency on a Nuget package C.

Now, when I create a Nuget package for A, it includes A.dll and B.dll but not C.dll

Can someone help me figure this out? How can I include all 3 .dlls?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891 for the feature request for `dotnet.exe pack` to the nuget client team. There are workarounds and debates in that issue.

Thx, Rob Relyea, NuGet Client Team

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because the fact is "dotnet pack" does not support what I am trying to do. However, the work around from Rocky is what I will end up doing to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly solve this by creating your own nuspec file. I am not sure how to do it within the context of the csproj file.

For example, with #csla we manage all our own [nuspec files](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/tree/master/NuGet/Definition) because there are so many moving parts.

Within a nuspec file you can list the specific files you want included, along with any package dependencies. So in your example it sounds like your nuspec would include the project A and B assemblies, so something like this:

```xml
<files>
  <file src="..\..\bin\Release\netstandard\netstandard2.1\**\A.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.1" />
  <file src="..\..\bin\Release\netstandard\netstandard2.1\**\B.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.1" />
</files>
```

And would declare the dependency to package C.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="netstandard2.1">
    <dependency id="C" version="1.0.0" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

You can see numerous examples in the #csla repo. Perhaps the closest (not using wildcards) is the [Csla.Blazor.nuspec](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/master/NuGet/Definition/Csla.Blazor.NuSpec) file.

Comment: Thanks Rocky. I was looking into that and I will try it. I guess then I will need to update by CI process to update the version numbers within the nuspec file. I am pretty sure this will work but, of course, I was hoping this could be done simpler. Seems to me the package should include all of it's dependencies easily. Oh well.